# How to enable basic authentication in NetworkManager openconnect applet (plasma-nm-oppenconnect)?

Tags: opensuse, cisco-vpn-client, networkmanager, kde-plasma-workspace

After latest upgrade, while trying to connect using nm-openconnect in NetworkManager I get the error "Server myserver.com requested Basic authentication which is disabled by default"

- How could I enable basic authentication in NetworkManager?
- Also how can I configure the server (ocserv) to use another type of authentication?

System Info :

```
OS : opensuse Tumbleweed 20170601  
Desktop : plasma5-desktop 5.9.5-1.1  
architecture : x86_64  
opeconnect : 7.08-1.2  
NetworkManager-openconnect : 1.2.4-1.2  
NetworkManager : 1.6.2-2.3  
plasma-nm5-openconnect : 5.10.0-1.1
```

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Also how can I configure the server (ocserv) to use another type of authentication?

On the server open the `/etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf` file (default configuration file) the file begins with a lot of explanation about alternative authentication methods. To enable *Certification based authentication* method you can follow the instructions on [vultr.com](https://www.vultr.com/docs/deploying-anyconnect-compatiable-vpn-server-with-certificate-verification-on-centos-7)

Don't bother with the `man ocserv`'s way of issuing client certificates. Just use easyrsa (as explained by vultr) and save yourself **A LOT** of hassle.

Eventually you'll get a certificate file supported by NetworkManager, AnyConnect client (on Android, iOS, Windows) and ...

### How could I enable basic authentication in NetworkManager?

Still not sure about this one. As specified in the manual of networkmanager-openconnect plugin, it's the plugin who is disabling basic auth by default. You have to pass some options to the plugin to enable the basic authentication. How can you make `nm` to do that? not sure. You'll get some idea from openconnect's [mailing list](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2016-July/003752.html)